# Slack channel not found. Private slack channel from a docker container

Tags: go, slack-api

I have set up a slack app to allow me to send notifications from my code to a private slack channel.

I have invited the bot to the channel, and when I run the app from the command line, all is good.

However, when I try and run it from a docker container, I get channel not found. If I try and use exactly the same code, and send a message to a bot in a public channel, no issues all is good.

Both bots have permissions, chat:write and chat:write.public

Why would this only be working on some machines and not others?

I know this probably doesn't have enough detail, but I'm not sure what is needed to help diagnose this.

More information:
Thanks to @Suyash Gaur I didn't know about the groups scope. I've now added groups:write and groups:history to the app, but am still getting the same error from the docker version of the app.

The membership of the channel I'm trying to write too shows

```
cwpr_notifications on Aug 3, 2021
Can post messages to specific channels in slack, send messages as @cwprnotifications, send messages to channels @cwprnotifications isn't a member of, manage private channels that cwpr_notifications has been added to and create new ones, and view messages and other content in private channels that cwpr_notifications has been added to.
```

I am using a bottoken and channel ID to send the message. Do I need something else for a private channel.

When I first used the bot from the command line run, I had to invite the app to the channel to get it to work, but surely I only need to do that once?

I've confirmed that the environment variables are getting passed in correctly.

Comment: no errors ? Nothing to help you fgure out ? sems a little weird

Comment: I have debug on.. the only thing I get back is 'channel not found'

Comment: "I know this probably doesn't have enough detail, but I'm not sure what is needed to help diagnose this." <- Can you share your dockerfile along with the code responsible for sending message?

Comment: dont you rely on some environment variables that were not set within the docker file ?

Comment: I wondered about the environment variables, but when I use the ones for the public channel, I have no issues, so they are being read OK. The same .env file is being used from the command line and from the docker inscance.

Answer (score 0):

With limited set of information provided, I can only say that:

If the public channel is accessible and private channel is not,

 It seems like an issue of scopes.

**For public channels**, scopes start with `channels:*`

 **For private channels**, scopes start with `groups:*`

Can you look into the app's configuration and confirm the permissions are configured correctly?